# while resolving module `firebase/firestore`, the Haste package `firebase` was found. However the module could not be found within the package

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo

I am using React-native [Expo-cli] with firebase v9.
When I tried to run my app in my real device using Expo Go it throws this particular Error every time.

```
Android Bundling failed 26102ms
While resolving module `firebase/firestore`, the Haste package `firebase` was found. However the module `firestore` could not be found within the package. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * `E:\Programming\React_Native\Firebase\firestore(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
  * `E:\Programming\React_Native\Firebase\firestore\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
```

I have also tried to change the version of firebase but the problem still exists.

But the thing is when I run the same app in web browser of Expo it's works perfectly Fine.

As my Pc is Low end I am not able to check on Emulator that's why I use Real Device.

This is the Screen Shot in Web

[image: This is the Screen Shot in Web]

This is the Screenshot on my Device[Android]

[image: Screenshot on Android]

Here is the Code I am Referring

https://github.com/ReactiveKoding/firebase-v9-crud

Do any one have encountered this same problem if yes can you help me to fix it !